How should this be written to work? =countifs(E:E,"=HP EliteBook 850 G7 Notebook PC")
I am just looking to count how many 850's are in our inventory. They are in column E and the count in that column will change ever single time. I type this in and nothing happens besides me seeing what I typed in. I do not get a count. Tried it 3 ways. Thank you for advice :)
=countifs(E:E,"=HP EliteBook 850 G7 Notebook PC")

=countifs(E:E,"HP EliteBook 850 G7 Notebook PC")

=countif(E2:E223,"=HP EliteBook 850 G7 Notebook PC")

Expecting a count in the cell i entered =countifs into.

You could have used wildcard operator * --> =COUNTIF(E:E,"* 850 *")

Please check whether you have turned on "Show Formulas" in the ribbon. Display or hide formulas - Microsoft Support
